# Авторизация в C# с использованием базы данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, авторизация

Пытаюсь сделать авторизацию + регистрацию пользователей для своего приложения на C#. Суть в том, что для этого должна использоваться база данных (в качестве базы данных используется MS Access), где при авторизации происходит поиск и сравнение полей login и password из БД с данными, вписанные в соответствующие поля в форме авторизации. При регистрации же login и password из полей записываются в соответствующие столбцы в БД. Добавляю новый источник данных, выбираю БД и при выборке таблиц выдает ошибку

> "<[user]>Не удается получить данные схемы для таблицы или представления [user]."

Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее решить. Сильно строго не судите. Это первый серьезный проект на C#.

Comment: опишите более детально проблему, приведите технологии которые используете и участки кода

Comment: Код еще не написан, т.к. только начал делать приложение. БД добавляю через "Добавить источник данных" во вкладке "Вид". Может, я с этим делаю что-то не правильно и для связи с БД на форму должен добавляться какой-либо элемент?

Comment: Я делал практические для студентов, надеюсь вам помогут, там все основные функции роботы с бд, используються как адаптеры так и ADO.NET http://rgho.st/7bnMFXJzB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем на форму элемент **bindingSource**, находим в его свойства **DataSource** нажамаем и выбираем **Add Project Data Source**.

Выбираем тип источника данных **Database**, после два раза жмем далее и появляеться окно в котором нужно выбрать подключение.

Жмем на **New Connection** где выбираем тип нашей бд, в вашем случае это **Microsoft Access Database File**, затем выбираем файл нашей базы данных кнопкой **Browse**.

Жмем **ОК**, вылазит окошко которое предложит вам скопировать файл бд к вам в проект, соглашаемся.

Все наша бд подключена к программе.